# Minio Distributed Mode Error All ServerPool Must Have Same Deployment ID

Tags: object, storage, minio, object-storage

I've been trying to setup Minio server in Distributed Mode using 2 nodes, but everytime I tried, I always get error "All serverPools should have same deployment ID expected xxx, got yyy".

I'm setting up minio on Ubuntu servers.

I followed the instruction in Minio official docs [here](https://docs.min.io/docs/distributed-minio-quickstart-guide.html), but I can't find any mention of this error or any tutorial to make the Deployment ID the same.

Does anybody know what this is or how to make the deployment ID the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've typically seen this happen when users attempt to do something similar to the following:

- Start MinIO with `minio server http://minio.example.net/mnt/disk-{1...4}`
- Later try to 'migrate' to distributed mode as `minio server http://minio-{1...4}.example.net/mnt/disk-{1...4}`

The second command is an entirely different topology, and results in a new deployment ID. When MinIO checks the existing backend disks, it sees that there is existing metadata, with a deployment ID that was generated based on the original topology. It then throws an error.

We would need to know quite a bit more about what you are attempting here - whether this is a fresh deployment, what MinIO version you are using, what the startup command was, etc, before being able to debug any further. *But* the above would be my guess as to what the issue is.

If this *is* a fresh deployment and you have no data to be concerned with, you can completely clean the backend drives of all data - including the `.minio.sys` folder at each path - and go from there. If you keep having the same issue with completely empty backend drives, then that is a little more unusual, and might be better suited as a Github issue so we can try to track that down further.